# Jquery Uniform Update doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, uniform

I'm using jquery uniform on one of the project I'm working on. Since this is admin panel, I truly don't have option to show. I will explain my problem

What I'm trying to do is quite simple. I'm adding some form elements (like select, check box, text input) to the page with ajax.

Every single thing works except re-styling those dynamically added form elements.

```
function step2 () {
    $.post( siteUrl + "includes/ajax/members/add-subscription.php?do=step2", $("#selectedSubscribers").serialize(), function( data ) { 
        $('.step2_content').html(data);
        $.uniform.update(); 
    });
 }
```

Anyone experienced similar problem? Even my onClick, onChange functions are working without a problem (dynamically added form elements), it is just, `$.uniform.update();` doesn't seem to work.

I thought processing data could take longer time so $.uniform.update(); is called before data is processed so I tried `$.ajax` with `async: false` with no luck.

I will be glad if anyone who experienced such problem or who knows the solution could help me out with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When `$.uniform()` is first called, it collects all the specified elements into an internal array of affected elements.  When you call `$.uniform.update()` it simply restyles those elements that were already collected.

To add additional elements, you may need to call `$.uniform()` again, passing a selector identifying only those new, dynamically added elements.

Comment: No idea why but this worked $( "select, input:checkbox, input:radio, input:file").uniform(); $.uniform.update(); without .update() still doesn't work and I don't get the point why do I have to use .update() after adding elements to the uniform.

Answer (score 5):

for load() if fix promblem

```
$('#dialog').load(url + ' #forload', function() {$('#dialog').find('select').uniform(), $('#dialog').find('input:checkbox').uniform()})
```

Comment: Thank you--I was having a problem getting uniform to style a select element after using .load() and this totally fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
$.uniform.update("#select_element_id");
```

In my case, the problem was solved.

Being old the version of uniform, may cause your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may be this

```
setTimeout("$('.uniform_element').uniform();",200);
```

200 or a higher number may need.

Comment: This solution is actually recommended per the uniform read and [relevant issue #270](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/issues/270)

Comment: This solution actually worked. In my case checkbox(s) were inside drop down

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $('.elementClass').uniform();
```