# How to apply style sheet on dynamic generate radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

here, I am using form wizard. Using ajax to load the data and data are append in html.

ajax code :

```
    $.ajax({

        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/listSiteUrl',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success == 1) {
                var row = '';
                var i = 1;

                $.each(response.row_data, function (index, value) {
                    row += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + value.url + "</td><td>" + value.p1_name + "</td><td hidden>" + value.id + "</td><td hidden>" + value.f_n + "</td><td><div class='radio-list'><label><input type='radio' id='f_n_val' name='select_val' data-url='" + value.url + "' data-pub='" + value.p1_name + "' data-id='" + value.id + "' data-follow='" + value.f_n + "' required='required'></label></div></td></tr>";
                    i++;
                });
                $("#results").html(row); 
              // $("input[type=radio]").uniform();

            } else {
                var row = '';
                row += "<tr><td colspan='4' class='text-center'>No Records Found</td></tr>";
                $("#results").html(row);
            }

        }

    });
```

How to apply style sheet on a radio button? you can show in image very clearly...

[image]

When I am using uniform style i.e. ($("input[type=radio]").uniform();) work fine and radio button style is applied bt problem in when I am checking validation that time it will look like in below image :

[image]

Please help me to find out the way to solve this.

Comment: you need to set the class to radio button.

Comment: give class on `input type='radio'` and apply your rule on css.

Comment: use `$.uniform.update()` after applying `.uniform()` to dynamically created elements. Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868101/jquery-uniform-update-doesnt-work

Comment: thank you @pokeybit, bt it didn't work

Comment: Try what Shree saying in the comment

Comment: @MayankPandeyz, done with that

Comment: @MayankPandeyz, done with that..

Answer (score 1):

You can create your class in css as

```
.myradio{
  // your code here
}
```

and then

```
$("input[type=radio]").addClass('myradio');
```

Comment: when I am using custom style sheet then radio button value not clickable why ? for radio button design i'm using a background image...